# How child processes gets terminated when the parent is killed using SIGINT?

Tags: bash, unix

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in $(seq 1  $1);
do
   ./extended&
done
wait
```

This is my bash script and I execute the extended binary as many times as specified in command line argument. When I kill the bash script using SIGINT the child processes also killed. I've called wait in the bash script I couldn't figure how the child processes are killed. I know that wait will make the parent to wait till child terminates.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` sends a `SIGHUP` (hang-up signal) to all children on exit by default.  If you don't want this behaviour use `disown -h`

From `man bash`:

*To prevent the shell from sending the signal to  a  particular job,  it  should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin or  marked  to  not  receive  SIGHUP
       using disown -h.*